# Wifi disabled on Dell Latitude E5570

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dell

I can't get my wifi to come up. Please see the output of wifi script below.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23175690/

Answer (score 0):

If this is a clean install, do a full system upgrade using ethernet connection. After a reboot, your wifi should work. (Happened to me too)

Comment: Unfortunately it's an upgrade, I'm hoping I don't have to do that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the driver needs to be updated. Below is the link to the instructions that worked for me.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208874